# Google Translate Dropdown behind background image

Tags: html, css

I am using Google Website Translator but when I translate the page to another language, a drop down appears on top of the browser causing all my content of my website to go down except for the background image.

My website is http://www.trialwebsite.comze.com/Index.html

You can check it and can view my source to know the problem. The code for the body and background photo is:

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: #555;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
line-height: 20px; 
background-color: #fff; 
background-image: url(images/templatemo_header.png);
background-position: top;
background-position:inherit;
background-repeat: repeat-x
}
```

Comment: for me its working ok, google translate menu is over all your site (including background)

Comment: no i mean the top background image behind the menus...when you change the language, a drop down appears and pushes all the content down but the top background image  do not move with the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the background outside the body, so it becomes a DOM element who google translate can move too.

insert this this just below your `<body>` tag:

```
<div class="background"></div>
```

Then add this to your stylesheet:

```
 .background {
     background-image: url(images/templatemo_header.png);
     height: 188px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
  }
```

EDIT: And remove the background property from body css rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following styles to your website's stylesheet:

```
.skiptranslate {display: none !important;}
```

This should hide the bar that Google places on your website after the translation finished.